# Problems getting telnet to connect to a python socket server

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, telnet

So I'm starting to work on a kind of Internet of Things project and the first issue I'm stumbling upon is having trouble in setting up a basic server. Using this guide, to do some initial tests, here is the code being used:

```
'''


   Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

s.close()
```

I can set the server up and it will listen on socket, but when i try to connect with telnet, it times out. Since I'm on a network in my college, could this be the reason why things aren't going through? I remember doing something like this in C a while back and it seemed to work then...

Comment: TELNET is a specific protocol - what if you open a raw connection?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a remote system or localhost? The code works fine for me if I telnet from localhost, so you may be dealing with a firewall issue if remote connections aren't working.

Comment: What happens when you connect using something other than telnet?  Like, for instance, if you write another python socket script to connect?

Comment: Or, more simply, use `nc`/`netcat` for testing instead of `telnet`. Just about every platform besides Windows comes with it nowadays, and a quick google will turn up your choice of Hobbit, GNU, or BSD API versions of netcat for Windows.

Comment: "*#now keep talking with the client*" how to talk without any `read/recv` and `write/send` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The code works, but doesn't send/receive from the client.  The following modest change makes the server send `beer tasty` to any lucky clients.

### source

```
'''
Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    conn.send('beer tasty\n')   # <==
    conn.close()
s.close()
```

test with Netcat in Linux. (Telnet also should work)

## test

```
$ echo beer | nc -q1 localhost 8888
Connected with 127.0.0.1:37484
beer tasty
```